# SubSelect or SubQuery

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery

Below will successfully find the product a customer has submitted
* http://inks-etc.com/Canon/canon_inkdesign.php?ID=114  The ID=114 came from the $_GET['ID'] and when into the SELECT to receive the products: Price, Product No., Description, Image.  Now I have been trying to get about 4 (LIMIT 4) more similar products to capture of the left side of the page so if the customer chooses a LC41 Black, I can provide LC41 Cyan, LC41 Magenta, LC41 Yellow as well.  I am thinking the 'SELECT Sub query' would be helpful.  Will you tell me what I must modify and even begin again to perform this task.

```
    $inksetc = htmlentities($_GET['ID']);

     $sql2 = "SELECT Id,   Product_Type,  Product_No ,  miniImageFarm

         FROM `Canon_INK`

         WHERE IN
             (SELECT Id= $inksetc FROM Canon_INK WHERE Id LIKE $inksetc) 

         LIMIT 4";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql2) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>
```

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using?

Comment: Probably mysql because he's using `mysqli()` functions in php.

Comment: I am using PhpMyAdmin

Comment: PhpMyAdmin is *not* a DBMS, it's a frontend/admin tool for the DBMS called MySQL

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a sub-query for this and you need wildcard `'%'` so that you could search by pattern and your `$sql2` should look like this therefore:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT Id,   Product_Type,  Product_No ,  miniImageFarm ";
$sql2 .= "FROM `Canon_INK` ";
$sql2 .= "WHERE Id LIKE '%".SUBSTR($inksetc,0,4)."%'";
```

I added for `%` for matching search.

Comment: That is invalid SQL syntax.

Comment: Thank You Edper for your LIKE / Substring.  The FireFox is having a difficult time accepting: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%'.SUBSTR(5,0,4).'%)ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4' at line 1 If you would like to see click here:  http://inks-etc.com/HP/hp_inkdesign.php?ID=5  Thank You Edper for ALL of your help :  )

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something like this:

```
SELECT Id, Product_Type, Product_No, miniImageFar
FROM Canon_INK
WHERE SUBSTR(Id, 0, 4) = SUBSTR($inksetc, 0, 4)
```

Read up on the `LIKE` operator; it does not say one string is like another, but rather that a string matches a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
$inksetc = htmlentities($_GET['ID']);// need to store LC41 in $_GET['ID'].

  $sql2 = "SELECT Id,   Product_Type,  Product_No ,  miniImageFarm

     FROM `Canon_INK`

     WHERE Id IN
         (SELECT Id FROM Canon_INK WHERE Id LIKE '%".$inksetc."%') // use Id instead of Id= $inksetc.

     LIMIT 4";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql2) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

 while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the "LC41 Black" type value is stored in the Product_No column - not the Id column. I'm also assuming that you don't want the original product to show up in the list of similar products.

You can therefore join the table with itself to get the results, rather than using a subquery:

```
SELECT  c.Id,  c.Product_Type,  c.Product_No,  c.miniImageFarm
FROM Canon_INK AS c
INNER JOIN 
    Canon_INK AS OriginalProduct
ON 
    SUBSTR(c.Product_No, 0, 4) = SUBSTR(OriginalProduct.Product_No, 0, 4)
AND
    c.Id != OriginalProduct.Id
WHERE
    OriginalProduct.Id = $intsect
LIMIT 4;
```

Your query is insecure at the moment - please do not escape things for SQL using the htmlentities function, instead have a look at [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Comment: Thank You David, I have this url to share with you: http://inks-etc.com/Canon/canon_inkdesign.php?ID=185 because it is providing me with a error I do not understand: Unknown column 'c.Id' in 'field list'  Any Suggestions.  Oh! I can confirm that you are right with all of the announcements made up-top. Very Good! Jason Kraft inks-etc.com P.S. I changed the $intsect to $inksetc (my company name)  You made it sound as if my company is an insect LOL!

Comment: No problem. Looked into your error - I think you might have copied the SQL incorrectly? Make sure that you include the "AS c" bit after "FROM Canon_INK".

Like this `$sql2 = "SELECT  c.Id,  c.Product_Type,  c.Product_No,  c.miniImageFarm FROM Canon_INK AS c INNER JOIN  Canon_INK AS OriginalProduct ON SUBSTR(c.Product_No, 0, 4) = SUBSTR(OriginalProduct.Product_No, 0, 4) AND c.Id != OriginalProduct.Id WHERE OriginalProduct.Id = $inksetc  LIMIT 4;";`

Comment: Did you try with the updated SQL which I included in my comment?